# Martices multiplication using c++ template

Tags: c++

Since you were so helpful, I have another question.

I have implemented matrices multiplication using templates, but I can not compile my code.

Here it is.

matrix.h:

```
#ifndef __MATRIX_H__
#define __MATRIX_H__

template <class T, int rows, int cols> class matrix {
public:
    T mat[rows][cols];
    matrix();
    matrix(T _mat[rows][cols]);
    matrix operator+(const matrix& b);
};

template <class T, int rows, int cols> matrix <T,rows,cols> :: matrix (T _mat[rows][cols]){
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            mat[i][j] = _mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}

template <class T, int rows, int cols> matrix <T,rows,cols> :: matrix (){
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

template <class T, int rows, int cols> matrix <T,rows,cols> matrix <T,rows,cols>::operator+(const matrix<T, rows, cols>& b){
    matrix<T, rows, cols> tmp;
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            tmp.mat[i][j] = this->mat[i][j] + b.mat[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

template <class T, int rows, int cols> template <int new_cols> matrix <T,rows,new_cols> matrix <T,rows,cols>::operator*(const matrix<T, cols, new_cols>& b){
    matrix<T,rows,new_cols> tmp;
    int i, j, k;
    T sum;
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
        for(j=0; j<new_cols; j++){
           sum = 0;
           for (k=0; k<cols; k++){
               sum += this->mat[i][k] * b.mat[k][j];
           }
           tmp.mat[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}



#endif
```

matrix.cpp:

```
#include "tar5_matrix.h"
int main(){

    int mat1[2][2] = {1,2,
                      3,4};
    int mat2[2][2] = {5,6,
                      7,8};
    int res[2][2];
    matrix<int, 2, 2> C;
    matrix<int, 2, 2> D;
    matrix<int, 2, 2> A = mat1;
    matrix<int, 2, 2> B = mat2;
    C = A+B;
    D = A*B;

    return 0;

}
```

When trying to compile, I get the following errors,

```
1>  tar5_matrix.cpp
1>c:\users\karin\desktop\lior\study\cpp\cpp_project\cpp_project\tar5_matrix.h(68): error C2039: '*' : is not a member of 'matrix<T,rows,cols>'

1>c:\users\karin\desktop\lior\study\cpp\cpp_project\cpp_project\tar5_matrix.cpp(14): error C2676: binary '*' : 'matrix<T,rows,cols>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Please advise.

Comment: Sorry, wrong line number. It is line 52. The closure '}' of the last function defined in matrix.h

Comment: Don't use double-underscores in your include guards, any name starting with __ is reserved for the implementation (i.e. the compiler, standard library and OS) to use.  If you use names with __ then you risk clashing with names in system headers. Just call it `MATRIX_H` or `SOME_PREFIX_MATRIX_H` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You have not defined `operator*` in the class body.

Comment: I did, this is the last function defined in matrix.h

Comment: @LiorAvramov: But you did not put it in the class body.

Comment: Can you please add that one line that needs to be put into the class body?

Answer (score 0):

As Oli points out, the problem is that you have not declared `operator*` to be a member method, but you are trying to *define* it as such. The two alternatives you have here are adding a declaration, or changing it to be a free function. I particularly prefer the free function approach, as the multiplication is not more of an operation on the left hand side than it is in the right hand side.

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M, size_t O>
matrix<T,M,O> operator*( matrix<T,M,N> const & lhs, 
                         matrix<T,N,O> const & rhs )
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention the declaration that needs to be included in the class?

Comment: @PraveenVinny: The better approach, which is what I did in the answer, is not to provide the operator as a member but as a free function (see the code above). That does not need a declaration within the class.

If it needs access to the internals, consider declaring it as a friend.